# How to send emails from django shell with AWS ses?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, django-anymail

I have verified my domain with AWS SES and as a result my site successfully does send password verification emails (via allauth).

I would, however, also like to be able to send emails based on local scripts. To do this I have been using django shell_plus:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("It works!", "This will get sent through anymail",
          "me@mysite.com", ["me@mysite.com"])
```

I get output of '1' suggesting this the email has been sent successfully but I do not receive an email

I think my config is correct given that the site does successfully send emails:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.amazon_ses.EmailBackend"
ANYMAIL = {
    "AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS": {
        "aws_access_key_id": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        "aws_secret_access_key": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        "region_name": "us-east-1",
    },
}
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do to send emails from the terminal i.e. without being directly logged into an AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

Was a basic error - I had the required settings in my production config file, but not in my dev config file